# After maven deploy snapshot to nexus get 404 not exists

Tags: maven, nexus

I use **mvn deploy:deploy-file** to publish snapshots to nexus.

The snapshot is created with timestamp in the following format *xxxx-1.0.0.0-20171206.163242.jar*

In addition the maven-metadata.xml file is updated with the name of the last snapshot.

Sometimes there is a race condition between the timestamp of the file name in the metadata and the real file name.

for example the file name is *xxxx-1.0.0.0-20171206.16324**2**.jar* and in metadata it would be *xxxx-1.0.0.0-20171206.16324**1**.jar*

I tried to use **-DuniqueVersion=false** in order to remove the timestamp but it seems that it does nothing and the filenames still contain timestamp

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: why are you using deploy:deploy-file and not just deploy?

Comment: The usual way is to use `mvn deploy` that's it...

Comment: Maven is the one that updates the maven-metadata.xml file, it downloads it, computes a new timestamp, and uploads it.  So it sounds like more than one maven client is deploying to this GAV at the same time.

Comment: Those artificats are not build by maven therefore we use the deploy-file according to this documentation http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html